# Fitting a Poisson dist and MLE

Tags: r, distribution, poisson, mle

I am trying to find the MLE estimate for lambda, the dataset is column1= date and time(Y-m-d hour:min:sec)- distributed by a Poisson.  column2=money in a certain account.
I kept getting an error message because it said the dataframe didn't have numerical values so I checked the classes:

```
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
[1] "numeric"
```

so I used the following command:

```
as.numeric(Capped_data_M$Date_Time - ISOdate(2019,01,01, hour=0, min=0, sec=0)
```

This made the dates into values like `6.556666`

I then attempted

```
Poifit <- fitdist(dateandtime,"poisson", method = "mle")
```

But I get this error message saying the distribution is not defined. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: [For a Poisson the MLE of lambda is just the average of the data](https://www.projectrhea.org/rhea/index.php/MLE_Examples:_Binomial_and_Poisson_Distributions_Old_Kiwi).

Answer (score 0):

From the `fitdist()` documentation in the `fitdistrplus` package, the `distr` argument should be:

> A character string "name" naming a distribution for which the corresponding density function dname, the corresponding distribution function pname and the corresponding quantile function qname must be defined, or directly the density function.

In other words, you should change your "poisson" to "pois"

```r
library(fitdistrplus)

dateandtime <- rpois(100, lambda = 1.3)

fitdist(dateandtime, "pois", "mle")
#> Fitting of the distribution ' pois ' by maximum likelihood 
#> Parameters:
#>        estimate Std. Error
#> lambda     1.25  0.1118033
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>